# Navigate flow from another managed bean

Tags: jsf, navigation, managed-bean, faces-flow

JSF 2.2 and Java EE 7

Let's say you have a Faces Flow called "/simple". It is already set and running.

Now you have another backing bean called DonkeyController.

```
@ViewScoped
public class DonkeyController {
    /* ... */
    public String doWork() {
        return "/simple";
    }
    public String doWorkRedirect() {
        return "/simple?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

This does not appear to work. How can you navigate (dynamically) to the start page of a Faces Flow from another backing bean?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is removed the leading slash. JSF 2.2 triggers just by the name of the Faces Flow. For my case "simple"